# Cannot change the None values in an SFrame using apply()

Tags: python, lambda, apply, graphlab, sframe

I am using this code to change the `None` values in the SFrame:

```
sarr['value'] = sarr['value'].apply(lambda x: '-1' if x is None else x)
```

After running this code, I still see the same `None` values, no effect. Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: What is sarr? If it is an array, is 'value' supposed to be value (don't ignore the quotation marks)?

Answer (score 0):

The following method of `SFrame` worked:

```
sarr = sarr.fillna('value', -1)
```